# Run GUI application using sudo from a tightvncviewer

Tags: raspbian, vnc, qt

I am trying to run Qtcreator with administrator in my remote raspberry Pi board using tightvncviewer from  my windows laptop.

I can run Qtcreator and debug my code without using sudo. But I want to debug my application in root access. for that, I usually running Qtcreator using sudo command"sudo qtcreator".

But when I try this from tightvncviwer the qtcreator pop up like a blank dialog box. I tried other GUI applications, that also shown like this. How I can run any GUI application using sudo in tightvncviewer.